# How to add a div dynamically by using Dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a the following static div:

```
<body>
  <div id="div1"></div>
....
```

I want to add a div with id "div1_1" within div1 dynamically by using dojo. How can I do it?

Comment: the inner div I prefer is centered vertically and horizontally.

Comment: With Dojo 0.9+ or the older 0.4?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it using just Dojo Base — no need to include anything, if you use the trunk or Dojo 1.3:

```
dojo.create("div", {id: "div1_1"}, "div1");
```

This line creates a div with id "div1_1" and appends it to the element with id "div1". Obviously you can add more attributes and styles in one go — read all about it in [the documentation for dojo.create()](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/create).

Answer (score 4):

Another option using flexible [dojo.place](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/place.html):

```
dojo.place("<div id='div1_1'></div>", "div1", /*optional*/ "only");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// dojo 1.7+ (AMD)
var n = domConstruct.create("div");
```

```
// dojo < 1.7
var n = dojo.create("div");
```

Answer (score 2):

[dojo/dom-construct](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dom-construct.html#create) also can be used for creating new nodes.

A sample usage is as follows;

```
require([ "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/_base/window" ], function(
        domConstruct, win) {
    // creates a new div and append it as the last child of the body
    domConstruct.create("div", null, win.body()));
});
```

dojo/dom-construct arguments are

1. tag  (div, h, img, li etc.)
2. attributes ( new nodes attributes)
3. reference node (where to place the new node)
4. position (default last)

you can checkout the documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
dojo.html.set(dojo.byId("div1"), "<div id='div1_1'></div>");
```

Comment: I think I need to add dojo.request("...") for dojo.html. What is the package?

Comment: sorry, it should be something like dojo.require(...)

Comment: got it: dojo.require("dojo.html");

Answer (score 0):

```
var divNode = document.createElement("div");
divNode.id = "div1_1";
document.body.appendChild( divNode );
```

This is a good way, it helps get past some node referencing issues in IE7 and you can continue to use the reference to the divNode later.

Comment: Use of this display an Error : Cannot find 'div' construct.