# Dynamically remove/add elements from div when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html

```
...
<div class="preview-list" data-layout="sidebar">

</div>
...
```

There is an array of elements that need to be dynamically inserted into an empty div with the "preview-list" class using javascript. When scrolling, you need to remove the invisible 5 elements from the div and add 5 elements from the bottom. If the user scrolls up, you need to remove the lower invisible 5 elements from the div and add the new 5 elements at the top. Also need to keep the order of the elements in the array when dynamically adding/removing elements from div

Tried to do as stated here:
[Dynamically add and remove the div on scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388755/dynamically-add-and-remove-the-div-on-scroll)

**This is similar to what is needed (the answer is marked as a solution to the problem from the link above), but it does not work to make the scrolling vertical (up-down), in the example above, the scrolling is horizontal**

(Sorry for my English)

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically add and remove the div on scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388755/dynamically-add-and-remove-the-div-on-scroll)